# How to use kapt from command line (with kotlinc)?

Tags: java, shell, kotlin, kapt, kotlinc

[Official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) instructs how to use `kapt` from Gradle and Maven. But how can I use `kapt` from command line, with `kotlinc`?

Comment: If you find nothing about this, you can try to run a Gradle build with the `--debug` log level and find the line that looks like `[KOTLIN] Kotlin compiler args: ...`. Find the one that's related to kapt, not the regular Kotlin compilation, and it will contain the required command line arguments.

Comment: @hotkey it seems to a good idea.

Comment: @hotkey Yup, that was my approach =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Add `tools.jar` to Kotlin compilers' classpath

As of Kotlin version 1.1.3-2, `kotlinc` does not add `tools.jar` to compiler's classpath. `tools.jar` is required by `kapt`.

As a workaround, you can patch `kotlinc`.

```
vim $KOTLIN_HOME/bin/kotlinc
```

Edit line 79.

From:

```
kotlin_app=("${KOTLIN_HOME}/lib/kotlin-preloader.jar" "org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader" "-cp" "${KOTLIN_HOME}/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar" $KOTLIN_COMPILER)
```

To:

```
kotlin_app=("${KOTLIN_HOME}/lib/kotlin-preloader.jar" "org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader" "-cp" "${KOTLIN_HOME}/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar" $KOTLIN_COMPILER)
```

**Note: `$JAVA_HOME` must point to JDK, not JRE.**

**Note: This is a hack.**

## Invoke `kotlinc` with right arguments

```
kotlinc -cp $MY_CLASSPATH \
-Xplugin=$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/kotlin-annotation-processing.jar -P \
plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:aptMode=aptAndStubs,\
plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:apclasspath=/path/to/SomeAnnotationProcessor.jar,\
plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:sources=./sources,\
plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:classes=./classes,\
plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3:stubs=./stubs \
/path/to/MyKotlinFile.kt
```

Replace:

- `$MY_CLASSPATH` with your desired classpath
- `/path/to/SomeAnnotationProcessor.jar` with actual path to some annotation processor
- `./sources`, `./classes` and `./stubs` with paths do directories where respective intermediate artifacts should be stored
- `/path/to/MyKotlinFile.kt` with path to the Kotlin file(s) you want to compile
- (optionally) `$KOTLIN_HOME` with the path to Kotlin's installation directory (you should already have this in your env)

**Note: -X arguments (*advanced options*) are non-standard and may be changed or removed without any notice**

**Note: `kapt`'s interface is undocumented. You can check the source code: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/plugins/kapt3/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt3/Kapt3Plugin.kt#L295**

---

This stuff was reverse-engineered from running `gradle build --debug` in `kotlin-examples/gradle/kotlin-dagger` (https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/kotlin-dagger).

This is just a starting point. I'm still not sure of a few things. Feel free to edit this answer.

Thanks to `runningcode`: https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/956#issuecomment-309080611

If it wasn't obvious: this stuff sucks. JetBrains just assumed that CLI doesn't matter and they made the crucial interfaces undocumented / reserved for internal use.